# Einstein Bots - Classic or Lightning Knowledge

Tags: einstein, lightning-knowledge, einstein-chatbot

I am working on presenting Einstein Service features to our executive team with high focus on Einstein bots. Currently our support team is using Lightning  console but Knowledge is still hosted in classic. If one of our use cases is to configure the bot to serve Knowledge articles to customers, should we migrate to Lightning Knowledge or can articles in classic knowledge be used? Any insight is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The out of box functionality won't support Classic Knowledge. I presume it's because there's differences at their core with regards to article types vs. record types and new functionality is being developed for Lightning Knowledge.

[Object Search (knowledge object)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.bots_service_deliver_knowledge_articles.htm&type=5) is noted here to only support the Knowledge object for Lightning Knowledge.

> Object search with the Knowledge object is supported for Lightning
> Knowledge only, and it isn’t supported with Knowledge in Salesforce
> Classic.

[Deliver Knowledge Articles with Article Answers (Beta)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.bots_service_article_answers.htm&type=5) also specifically mentions using Lightning Knowledge

> **Use your Lightning Knowledge base** to create an FAQ-based bot in
> minutes with Article Answers. Using clicks, not code, admins can set
> up a bot to return fields from knowledge articles directly in the
> conversation

However, you are able to call [flows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_call_flow_action.htm)/[invocable apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_call_apex_action.htm) which I presume would allow you to interact with any object. The downside is that you have to devise all the logic (criteria to match article, etc). I have no way of testing that Classic Knowledge works in that regard other than to say if you can get it in apex/flow, you should be able to use that feature within Einstein Bots.

Comment: Thanks for your response Kris. My understanding is Einstein Article Recommendations is used for support agents to resolve the cases and I understand that Lightning knowledge is required there. Would the same feature be used in Einstein bots for clients as well? Or is there flexibility to display articles from Classic Knowledge for Einstein bots ? Thanks again!

Comment: My mistake. Are you referring to this [beta](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.bots_service_article_answers.htm&type=5) or do you have a link to whatever feature you're thinking of? There's also the ability to take "action" which allows you to call apex/flows so I'm not clear on whether you're asking about some particular feature you read/see

Comment: Both the beta feature you specified (Article Answers) and the "Object Search" action that I am looking into seem to indicate that Lightning knowledge is needed. I wonder if there is an alternative approach to access Classic knowledge articles via Einstein Bot.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I updated my answer. I would suggest looking into the calling a flow/invocable apex as you should be able to get information for any type of object (that you can access in those tools).

Comment: Thanks for your insight Kris! Appreciate it!